# Как мне правильно обновить Oracle APEX с нынешней до версии 3.2.1.?

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex

Я пробовал удалить полностью старый Oracle APEX для того, чтобы его обновить его. Моя версия Oracle express edition это XE11g. И я хочу установить Oracle APEX версии 3.2.1. Но вот такие вопросы возникли сразу:

1. Правда ли, что в интерфейс Oracle APEX 3.2.1. уже встроен Restful Data Services:

   Я имею в виду те службы RESTful services, которые можно использовать как для того, чтобы создавать ссылки Web References для веб-приложений на Oracle так и для создания Restful модулей(темплейте, хендлеры, возможность посмотреть результат sql запроса, сконвертированный в один из определённых форматов, конечно же на выбор пользователя(JSON,CSV, XML и.т.д.) через браузер и/или даже скачать результат этого запроса в виде отдельного файла) для упрощения запросов к базам данных через HTTP/HTTPS запрос?
2. Что я должен у себя на сервере Oracle sql проверить и вообще сделать, чтобы убедиться, что он готов для обновления apex до новой версии, чтобы не было потом никаких конфликтов(вероятнее всего из за останков ресурсов от старой версии апекса) или багов(особенно критических) не было? Прошу ас, даже умоляю перечислить тот список действий в этом случае, что я должен делать.

Comment: Не совсем ясно. БД 11g включает, насколько помню, версию 4.2. Инструкция по обновлению есть тут: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/upgrade-apex-for-xe-154969.html. Да, полноценная версия APEX включает как админ-часть RESTful, позволяющая сервисы создавать, так и клиентскую, позволяющую к ним обращаться. Всё, что нужно проверить для обновления по шагам указать в Installation Guide соответствующей версии. Вообще, для полноты жизни я бы рекомендовал перейти на Personal Edition, если, конечно, цели использования позволяют.

Comment: Я обновил APEX , но теперь при заходе на: http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/apex_admin у меня появляется диалоговое окошко НА ВСЕХ браузерах , чтобы я ввёл логин и пароль. Но так быть не должно. Я должен свободного без этой фигни заходить по этой ссылки на форму авторизации своего аккаунта в апексе. Скажите : что мне делать ?

Comment: Это какая-то проблема с авторизацией XML DB. Поищите в сети, я видел решение скриптом.

Comment: Спасибо , а как по точнее это в гугле вбить , чтобы найти вероятно то , что надо ?

Comment: Ааааа. Нашёл. Спасибо , что подсказали , но я пробовал через запуск скрипта apxconf сделать , на что вы намекали , но все равно при запуске апексной страницы вновь мне показывается этот (картинка ошибки здесь): http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualfile.aspx?id=19232433 .Почему ?